How do I optimally read latest data from different tables in openmrs database
I am trying to uniquely read latest patient data from openmrs database but it takes a lot of time and I want to know if their is a way I can optimize my SQL code to be efficient.
below is the initial query
SELECT
    pid2.identifier AS HospitalNumber,
    pid1.identifier AS UniqueID,
    person.gender AS Gender,
    MAX(encounter.encounter_datetime) AS LatestVisitDate,
    CONCAT(pn.given_name, ' ', pn.family_name) AS Patient_Name,
    CAST(psn_atr.value AS CHAR) AS Phone_No,
    pa.address1 AS Patient_Address,
    pa.city_village AS Patient_LGA,
    pa.state_province AS Patient_State,
    MAX(IF(obs.concept_id = 159599, obs.value_datetime, NULL)) AS ART_Start_Date
--    MAX(IF((obs.concept_id=165708 and encounter.form_id=27 AND obs.obs_datetime <= @endDate AND obs.voided =0),container.last_date,null)) as Pharmacy_LastPickupdate
FROM patient_identifier AS pid2
JOIN patient_identifier AS pid1 ON pid2.patient_id = pid1.patient_id
INNER JOIN encounter ON encounter.patient_id = pid2.patient_id
INNER JOIN person ON person.person_id = pid2.patient_id
INNER JOIN person_name AS pn ON pn.person_id = pid2.patient_id
LEFT JOIN person_attribute AS psn_atr ON psn_atr.person_id = pid2.patient_id
    AND psn_atr.person_attribute_type_id = (SELECT person_attribute_type_id FROM person_attribute_type WHERE name = 'Telephone Number')
LEFT JOIN person_address AS pa ON pa.person_id = pid2.patient_id
LEFT JOIN obs ON obs.person_id = pid2.patient_id
WHERE pid2.identifier_type = 5 AND pid1.identifier_type = 4
AND encounter.voided = 0 AND pid1.voided = 0
GROUP BY pid2.identifier, pid1.identifier, person.gender, person.birthdate, Patient_Name, Phone_No, Patient_Address, Patient_LGA, Patient_State;

I have tried using a subquery for my query but I discovered that more rows were added which is not what I want
below is the query I tried
SELECT
    pid2.identifier AS HospitalNumber,
    pid1.identifier AS UniqueID,
    person.gender AS Gender,
    encounter.encounter_datetime AS LatestVisitDate,
    CONCAT(pn.given_name, ' ', pn.family_name) AS Patient_Name,
    CAST(psn_atr.value AS CHAR) AS Phone_No,
    pa.address1 AS Patient_Address,
    pa.city_village AS Patient_LGA,
    pa.state_province AS Patient_State,
    obs_art_start_date.max_art_start_date AS ART_Start_Date
FROM patient_identifier AS pid2
JOIN patient_identifier AS pid1 ON pid2.patient_id = pid1.patient_id
INNER JOIN encounter ON encounter.patient_id = pid2.patient_id
INNER JOIN person ON person.person_id = pid2.patient_id
INNER JOIN person_name AS pn ON pn.person_id = pid2.patient_id
LEFT JOIN person_attribute AS psn_atr ON psn_atr.person_id = pid2.patient_id
    AND psn_atr.person_attribute_type_id = (SELECT pa_type.person_attribute_type_id FROM person_attribute_type AS pa_type WHERE pa_type.name = 'Telephone Number')
LEFT JOIN person_address AS pa ON pa.person_id = pid2.patient_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        obs.person_id,
        MAX(obs.value_datetime) AS max_art_start_date
    FROM obs
    WHERE obs.concept_id = 159599
    GROUP BY obs.person_id
) AS obs_art_start_date ON obs_art_start_date.person_id = pid2.patient_id
WHERE pid2.identifier_type = 5 AND pid1.identifier_type = 4
    AND encounter.voided = 0 AND pid1.voided = 0;


Can you please read: How to check performance of mysql query?, and follow the instructions in the accepted answer?

I resorted to using a subquery which should run and rejoin the query but I am having duplicate hospital numbers after running the query

Can you add the EXPLAIN output for the first query to the question? If you might not be familiar, simply put the word explain before the SELECT.
